# What is the target hash for a certain security level in TeamSpeak 3?

Tags: cryptography, hash, salt, identity, voip

In the VoIP software TeamSpeak 3 there are "security levels" to proof someone's identity. According to [this question][1], it is based on the proof-of-work algorithm Hashcash, generating hashes of a string plus an incrementing integer until the resulting hash fits a certain pattern.

What we have is an UID and an "identity string".
The UID is completely static and doesnt change when increasing the security level, while the identity string does.
The UID contains exactly 28 Base64 characters. The identity string however, follows the following scheme: $integer."V".$(204 chars Base64). Also the Base64 encoded part of the identity string has to include the UID, because the identity string is the only information you get when exporting an identity to fully recover it later (including the UID).

I've already tried to compare the hashes of the identity string and those of the UID - neither the hashes of the identity string itself on different security levels nor these hashes compared to those of the UID dont seem to follow a clearly visible pattern. So my assumption is that the identity string gets somehow changed statically in the binary, hashed and after that compared to the hash of the UID. But I have no idea on how to approach that.

I currently have no further idea on how to continue searching for the pattern, so how should I start finding the correct pattern required for the hash to be a "good hash" with a certain security level?

Comment: What you're essentially asking is to reverse-engineer the TeamSpeak3 client to figure out how it does its crypto. I'm not sure this question is answerable on this site.